# jQuery Replace One Div with Another

Tags: jquery

I need to replace one div with another and also i need another container to be removed. Please, see my code:

```
<a id="load-more" href="#">
<div class="text">Load more</div>
<div id="infscr-loading">
<img alt="Loading..." src="../loading_small.gif" style="display: none; ">
<div">No more posts to load</div>
</div>
</a>
```

I need this:

```
<span class="text">Load more</span>
```

replace with this:

```
<div">No more posts to load</div>
```

So, my result should be:

```
<a id="load-more" href="#">
<div">No more posts to load</div>
<div id="infscr-loading">
<img alt="Loading..." src="../loading_small.gif" style="display: none; ">
</div>
</a>
```

It's possible to do?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try:

```
$('.text').replaceWith(...);
```

Docs at http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Answer (score 1):

Your markup has an error in the `<div">` tag, probably you accidentally removed the class name or id. I'll assume the replacement div has an `id` attribute.

To change the contents of the `<div class="text">` bit you need to do:

```
$('div.text').replaceWith($('#replacement'));
```

This both eliminates the `text` div and moves the `#replacement` div to the position of the `text` div.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.text').replaceWith($('#replacement').html());
```